# Selenium scripts compiled or interpreted?

Tags: eclipse, selenium, scripting, automation, interpreter

Running the selenium webdriver scripts in eclipse I was getting compilation errors.I had always thought that scripts are interpreted on-the-fly in the browser.Also since I have installed only jre and not jdk,why are the scripts getting compiled before running on the browser?Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Java Tests get always compiled but under different step testCompile. They never get interpreted on Java